# How to place a TextNode into a div instead of body

Tags: javascript

how to place a `TextNode` into a div instead of body, thank you in advance! 
Sorry if I am so unexperienced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to create a h1 element with some text.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var h = document.createElement("H1");
            var t = document.createTextNode("Hello");
            h.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(h);
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't see any `div` here, anyway, use `var someEle = document.getElementbyId(DIV's ID); someEle.appendChild(h);` should work. See [Document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) inspect these functions' return, and choose one that matches most.

Comment: You can also create a div instead of a h1 and append that div to the body or any other element. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to add a div to Body and then look for it using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```
<body>

<div id="myButtonContainer">
    <p>Click the button to create a h1 element with some text.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var myButtonContainer = document.getElementById("myButtonContainer");
        myButtonContainer.style.display='none';

        var h = document.createElement("H1");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Hello");
        h.appendChild(t);

        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        myDiv.appendChild(h);
     }
</script>

</body>
```

You can check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmgwya58/1/

Comment: Thanks, now how would you have that in a new htlm file? (to be able to get the result and print it without printing the button?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood what you are trying to achieve but I update my example with a code that hides the button after clicking on it. I hope it helps.